# Why does my media selection script write to ONLY the first input field?

Tags: jquery, javascript, metabox, media

So I'm creating a metabox for a couple extra featured images to show on a postloop.  Simple stuff I thought until I writing the script for the extra images.

Here is what I have so far:

[image: two form fields]

So I've made a script to call up the media box and I can get it to write in what I need but when calling up the second media box it simply writes back to the first every time, even though my selector should be different.  Here is the script:

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';


$(function() {
    var meta_image_frame;

    function saveImage(e,uiElement){

            e.preventDefault();

            if ( meta_image_frame ) {
                meta_image_frame.open();
                return;
            }

            meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
                title: meta_image.title,
                button: { text:  meta_image.button },
                library: { type: 'image' }
            });

            meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){
                var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                $(uiElement).val(media_attachment.url);
            });

            // Opens the media library frame.
            meta_image_frame.open();

    }

    $('#fa_img1-button').click(function(e){
        saveImage(e,'#fa_img1');
    });

    $('#fa_img2-button').click(function(e){
        saveImage(e,'#fa_img2');
    });

});


})( jQuery );
```

As you can see I call upon the ID fa_img1-button and fa_img2-button for the button clicked and the ID of the form field which is fa_img1 & 2

Thoughts?

Comment: If you could provide the html, too, that would help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is because of the first "if", the good text field in only set the first time

to change that, you can add a "data" arguement in HTML and change the JavaScript code like that (look the modification in `meta_image_frame.on('select'`...)

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $(function() {

        var meta_image_frame;

        function saveImage(e, uiElement) {

            e.preventDefault();

            if (meta_image_frame) {
                meta_image_frame.field = $("#" + $(e.target).data("field"));

                meta_image_frame.open();
                return;
            }

            meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
                title : "meta_image.title",
                button : {
                    text : "meta_image.button"
                },
                library : {
                    type : 'image'
                }
            });

            meta_image_frame.on('select', function() {
                var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state()
                        .get('selection').first().toJSON();
                meta_image_frame.field.val(media_attachment.url);
            });

            // Opens the media library frame.
            meta_image_frame.open();

        }

        $('#fa_img1-button').click(function(e) {
            saveImage(e, '#fa_img1');
        });

        $('#fa_img2-button').click(function(e) {
            saveImage(e, '#fa_img2');
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

you can use it with this HTML code :

```
<input id="fa_img1" type="text" value=""/>
<br/>
<input id="fa_img1-button" type="button" data-field="fa_img1"
    value="Upload Image"/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input id="fa_img2" type="text" value=""/>
<br/>
<input id="fa_img2-button" type="button" data-field="fa_img2"
    value="Upload Image"/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Clever, that appears to work.  I guess I'm not sure what you mean about the good text field?  I'm still unsure why my approach didn't work the first time.  Is it that the meta_image_frame has to be set for these values each time?